# Как писать "экспортно ориентированный"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

*О необходимости поддержки экспортно ориентированных предприятий других отраслей экономики неоднократно говорила губернатор Югры Наталья Комаров.* Как писать "экспортно ориентированный": через дефис, раздельно, слитно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Орфографический словарь Лопатиных "Слитно, раздельно или через дефис?" фиксирует раздельное написание: **экспортно ориентированный**. Хотя в "интернетах" (и даже в книгах) встречаются любые варианты, увы.

Answer (score 1):

1) Д**ля специалистов это термин с дефисным написанием:**

В качестве одной из основных проблем производители **экспортно-ориентированной** 
продукции назвали недостаток дешевых финансовых ресурсов у российских компаний, 
необходимых им для расширения производства и совершенствования качества 
продукции. 
https://www.exportcenter.ru/mnenie-eksportera/repots/repotr_berery_and_opportunities.pdf

Термин используется в текстах очень авторитетных организаций.

**2) По общим правилам письма это наречие и прилагательное с раздельным написанием.**

Но вот в чем проблема: кроме специалистов, это сочетание никто не употребляет. **Отсюда раздельное написание должно иметь нулевую частотность.**

**И еще один момент**. Экспортно ориентированный ― это ориентированный на экспорт, то есть слово соотносится с **подчинительной связью**, а такие слова **по правилам должны писаться слитно**. Или **наречие должно сливаться с прилагательным**  для образования термина и тоже писаться слитно ― это тоже по правилам. Но при слитном написании слово **неудобно читается**, вот его и пишут через дефис **как промежуточную форму**.

Comment: Вы посмотрите поиском по книгам в Google. Увидите, какая там частотность. В книгах всё же чаще пишут правильно.

Comment: В каких книгах, здесь серьезные книги должны быть.  У нас эта проблема существует для всех терминов на  "-ориентированный". Термину неудобно существовать в виде сочетания, и терминология должна быть однозначной. Ведущая структура в каждой области должна эту терминологию задавать, а не правила.  Я однажды написала в какую-то организацию по поводу выражения "личностно-ориентированный", указывая на неграмотное письмо. Мне ответили, что да, конечно, раздельно надо писать. Но на этом всё кончилось, должно быть, отвечающему тоже объяснили. как надо писать.

Comment: Вот пример из ["Экономической энциклопедии"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=eh-5AAAAIAAJ&q=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&dq=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrvPyv96DZAhUEC-wKHRc_CFM4PBDoAQgtMAI), не знаю, будут ли Вам видны две ссылки в ней. Но я ошибся, через дефис встречается намного чаще — прошу извинить.

Comment: Грамота писала (ссылку а потерял), что слитно — не ошибка, хотя словарь дает только раздельное написание. Про дефис — ни слова.

Comment: В Грамоте сидят обычные пользователи языка. Да, у них образование и опыт работы,  это плюс. Но это работа, им задают очень много вопросов, им трудно уделить каждому максимум внимания, и это минус. А умение логично мыслить и интуитивное чувство языка - они вообще  у всех разные. Поэтому Грамота - это только мнение, пусть и достаточно авторитетное, но вовсе не единственное решение вопроса.